# PHP script causes segmentation fault then the browser asks me to download the .php file with nothing in it?

Tags: php, segmentation-fault

I've noticed an unusual problem with some of my php programs.  Sometimes when visiting a page like profile.edit.php, the browser throws a dialogue box asking to download profile.edit.php page.  When I download it, there's nothing in the file.  profile.edit.php is supposed to be a web form that edits user information.

I've noticed this on some of my other php pages as well.   I look in my apache error logs, and I see a segmentation fault message:

```
[Mon Mar 08 15:40:10 2010] [notice] child pid 480 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

And also, the issue may or may not appear depending on which server I deploy my application too.

**Additonal Details**
This doesn't happen all the time though.  It only happens sometimes.  For example, profile.edit.php will load properly.  But as soon as I hit the save button (form action="profile.edit.php?save=true"), then the page asks me to download profile.edit.php.   Could it be that sometimes my php scripts consume too much resources?

**Sample code**

Upon save action, my profile.edit.php includes a data_access_object.php file.  I traced the code in data_access_object.php to this line here

```
 if($params[$this->primaryKey])
 {
                        $q = "UPDATE $this->tableName SET ".implode(', ', $fields)." WHERE ".$this->primaryKey." = ?$this->primaryKey";
                        $this->bind($this->primaryKey, $params[$this->primaryKey], $this->tblFields[$this->primaryKey]['mysqlitype']);
}
 else
{
$q = "INSERT $this->tableName SET ".implode(', ', $fields);
}
// Code executes perfectly up to this point
// echo 'print this'; exit; // if i uncomment this line, profile.edit.php will actually show 'print this'.  If I leave it commented, the browser will ask me to download profile.edit.php
if(!$this->execute($q)){ $this->errorSave = -3; return false;}
// When I jumped into the function execute(), every line executed as expected, right up to the return statement.
```

And if it helps, here's the function execute($sql) in data_access_object.php

```
function execute($sql)
{

        // find all list types and explode them
        // eg. turn ?listId into ?listId0,?listId1,?listId2 
        $arrListParam = array_bubble_up('arrayName', $this->arrBind);

        foreach($arrListParam as $listName)
           if($listName)
           {
                $explodeParam = array();
                $arrList = $this->arrBind[$listName]['value'];
                foreach($arrList as $key=>$val)
                {
                        $newParamName = $listName.$key;
                        $this->bind($newParamName,$val,$this->arrBind[$listName]['type']);
                        $explodeParam[] = '?'.$newParamName;
                }
                $sql = str_replace("?$listName", implode(',',$explodeParam), $sql);
           }

        // replace all ?varName with ? for syntax compliance
        $sqlParsed = preg_replace('/\?[\w\d_\.]+/', '?', $sql);
        $this->stmt->prepare($sqlParsed);

        // grab all the parameters from the sql to create bind conditions
        preg_match_all('/\?[\w\d_\.]+/', $sql, $matches);
        $matches = $matches[0];

        // store bind conditions
        $types = ''; $params = array();
        foreach($matches as $paramName)
        {
                $types .= $this->arrBind[str_replace('?', '', $paramName)]['type'];
                $params[] = $this->arrBind[str_replace('?', '', $paramName)]['value'];
        }

        $input = array('types'=>$types) + $params;



        // bind it
        if(!empty($types))
        call_user_func_array(array($this->stmt, 'bind_param'), $input);

        $stat = $this->stmt->execute();
        if($GLOBALS['DEBUG_SQL'])
                echo '<p style="font-weight:bold;">SQL error after execution:</p> ' . $this->stmt->error.'<p>&nbsp;</p>';

        $this->arrBind = array();
        return $stat;
}
```

Comment: @Brett would be correct -- IF the file that was downloaded contained PHP code. In this case I suspect something else is at play. Does this just happen with one file and if so, could you please post some of the source of sed file?

Comment: Hmm..
I am figuring the same issue..
Sometimes when I visit Amazon and click on different categories, I am asked to save a file instead of opening it directly.
Which browser are you using? I am currently using FireFox 3.6

Comment: In firefox 5.8.2, it asks me to download sometimes.  In IE 8, sometimes I get a "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage.  Diagnose Connection Problem".  No useful error messages.  and this all happens "sometimes"

Comment: I am stumped! Is this Apache or IIS? If Apache, is it mod_php or fastcgi or normal CGI?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 9.10, Apache 2, mysql 5 and php 5.  Not sure about the mod_php or fastcgi or normal cgi.  How do I determine that?

Comment: call_user_func_array() - aren't the parameters reversed?  That might cause some issues...  Or wait, that's 2 arrays, are you actually passing a callback function to it?  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php

Comment: @John: Create a PHP file which contains this code: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` -- This will tell you if it's mod_php or fastcgi.

Comment: @Josh here's my phpinfo http://copycat.glacialsummit.com/phpinfo.php

Answer (score 1):

That is likely caused by incorrect server configuration. The server is sending the file directly, not interpreting it as a PHP program. Since you're using Apache, the following configuration setting ([from here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php)) should fix the problem:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

**Edit:** There appears to be a deeper problem. See comments under this answer and on the original question.

Comment: The server's not sending the PHP file directly if it's empty... something else is at play here.

Comment: You're right. Judging from the additional information, it looks like a deeper problem. Should I delete this answer as per http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37738/when-or-should-you-delete-your-incorrect-answer ?

Comment: The bottom line of the highest voted answer to that question on meta is "Just because it isn't exactly right, doesn't mean it doesn't add any value to the OP or future readers." So I would say no, don't delete, just edit and make it clear that while this is the most common case, it doesn't appear to apply here. I guess. Anyone else want to weigh in? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Also, be careful with browser caching. Even if applying the correct settings and the right file handler, the browser still prompt for a download of the file.
This can be fixed by rebooting the browser/emptying the browser cache.

Comment: I don't think this applies to his issue.

Answer (score 0):

This typically means you do not have PHP installed or configured correctly on the server.

Comment: In this case it's something else. He has PHP installed, it's just segfaulting when he executes an SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be 
`AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml` in the httpd.conf

I'm saving my answer because it's a fix but his real problem is the use of "action" in the HTML form. 
The form should be:

```
<form action="myphpfile.php" method="get">
  <input type="hidden" name="save" value="true" />
  First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" /><br />
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

You don't use a query in the form action you place a hidden input. I think that is why it seg faults. I would not use "get" as the method you should use "post" if you are going to save data. I actually use "post" all the time.

Comment: He has PHP installed OK, the issue is PHP is segfaulting when he executes a specific SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

What does the final SQL statement being generated look like? Where you have:

```
// echo 'print this'; exit;
```

What if you changed that to:

```
echo "Query: $q";
exit;
```

And posted the results in your question...

From what I can tell, your query will look like:

```
INSERT some_table SET field1, field2, field3
```

When it should be:

```
INSERT INTO some_table SET field1='value 1', field2='value 2', field3='value 3'
```

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if your [Apache request timeout](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#timeout) is less than than both the [php execution timeout](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) and the time required to run the script.

When the Apache timeout is reached, apache appears to close the connection. The browser sees the connection cleanly closed but does not have any content and so isn't able to recognise what to do with it, so falls back to the default behaviour for unrecognised content by asking you if you want to save the file.

Uncommenting your 'print this' echo statement and exiting outputs some text to the browser instead of entering the long running process. The Apache timeout is not reached, and the browser has content it knows it should display by default.

The occasional occurrence might be explained if the script varies in processing time, only occasionally exceeding the apache timeout. Or perhaps your script is blocking somewhere.

If the script timeout is always lower than the apache timeout, you'll get the more informative 'Fatal error: Maximum execution time...' error instead.